# how to mark line in database in Crystal-report?

Tags: c#, crystal-reports

i have crystal-report that show my DataBase.

how i can mark line in the crystal-report ?

for example: i run any query that return one line - and i want

to see all the table - and only this line will be mark

thank's in advance

Answer (score 0):

what do you mean by show my database.
are you saying it display data from a table. 
there is a line control in the crystal reports , which you can use to draw a line.

let me know if i didnt understand ur question.

Parminder

Comment: thank's for the help, i mean to remark line from the database (remark row)